# Do I need to open-source my operating system if I used grub as my bootloader in my ISO

Tags: grub, gnu, gpl

Ok, so I was following the bare bones tutorial on how to create an OS and then I saw a warning when adding grub to the ISO that I have GPLed software in my program (OS). According to the GPL, I need to open-source my program, because I used GPLed software. Do I need to do it? If so how to prevent it

Comment: I guess https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ or https://law.stackexchange.com/ would be better suited to answer this question. Of course you might have to provide more details than currently.

Comment: As already commented, ask on opensource SE. I expect the answer will be that you have just combined two packages and your OS has not integrated grub as into the actual source code. As an example, if you could replace `grub` with `lilo` then you are ok.

Comment: Your software did not use GPL'd grub, GPL.d grub used your software. And why would it apply. There are plenty of closed software being run by GPL'd Linux, and no one suggests that they should be opened. All you require to do is make the grub source available.